# Bash: count occurrences of value in column x based on value in column y

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a string like this.

```
data = "state:: 4 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.01:5080;transport=udp

state:: 4 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.11:5080;transport=udp

state:: 4 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.03:5080;transport=udp 

state:: 4 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.26:5080;transport=udp

state:: 2 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.26:5080;transport=udp 

state:: 2 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.11:5080;transport=udp 

state:: 1 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.07:5080;transport=udp"
```

I need to write a bash script to count how many times each IP e.g 192.168.26 have state 4 or state 2. 
(this string doesn't contain '/n')

I am unable to parse this string and count values according to each IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work for every possible combination that you might have but it works for the small sample you provided:

```
sed  "1,\$s/state/\nstate/g" file | grep state > NewFile
for IPADDR in $(cat NewFile | cut -d"@" -f2|cut -d":" -f1|sort -n|uniq);do
  for STATE in 2 4 ;do
    LineCount=$(grep "${IPADDR}" NewFile |grep "state:: ${STATE}"| wc -l)
    echo "For IP address ${IPADDR}, status:: ${STATE} lines count is ${LineCount}"
  done
done | grep -v "is 0"$
```

you can add as many different STATE numbers you want on the for loop inside

Basically you are inserting a new line character before each occurrence of the string `state` making your big blob of data, separating in to multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks @MelBurslan for such a quick reply.
Problem is that I do know the IP address prior. I need to extract distinct IPs from string and upon that IPs list, I need to get the count.
Sorry, I added the new lines to make the string more readable.But in actual, this is a long single string(of multiple lines) without new lines.

Comment: Please see the modified commands in the light of your new requirements

Comment: Please read [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Comment: @SatoKatsura I'm old school :)

Answer (score 0):

Find unique IP's and count each with state 4 or 2

```
for addr in $(grep -o '@[^:]\+' file | sort -u); do 
    echo -n ${addr#@}:\ 
    grep -c ":: [24].*${addr#@}" file
done
```

Or do task with awk

```
awk -F '[: @;=]+' '
    $2 ~ /^[24]$/{
        count[$6]++
        }
    END {
        for(i in count)
            print(i, count[i])
        }
    ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my tiny monster.

```
#!/bin/bash 
# monsterr.sh

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    printf "%s\n" "Syntax error."
    exit 2
fi

data="$1"

tmp=tmp$$
mkdir $tmp

parse() {
    state=
    ip=
    i=0
    while read l; do
        ((i++))
        if [ $(($i%2)) -eq 0 ]; then
            if [ $(($i%4)) -eq 2 ]; then
                state=$l
            else
                IFS=: read x ip x < <(printf %s $l)
                IFS=@ read x ip < <(printf %s $ip)
                printf "%s\n" $state >> "$tmp/$ip"
            fi
        fi
    done <  <(printf "%s\n" $data)
}


report() {
    cd $tmp
    for f in * ; do
        declare -a count
        printf "IP: %s\n" $f
             while read s ; do
                ((count[$s]++))
            done < $f
        for s in ${!count[@]}; do
            printf "State: %s, count: %s\n" $s ${count[$s]}
        done
        printf '\n'
        unset count
    done
    cd - 2 > /dev/null
}

parse
report

rm -r $tmp
```

Usage:

```
$ data="state:: 4 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.01:5080;transport=udp state:: 4 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.11:5080;transport=udp state:: 4 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.03:5080;transport=udp state:: 4 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.26:5080;transport=udp state:: 2 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.26:5080;transport=udp  state:: 2 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.11:5080;transport=udp state:: 1 caller_contact:: sip:123456789@192.168.10.07:5080;transport=udp"
$ ./monsterr.sh "$data"
IP: 192.168.10.01
State: 4, count: 1

IP: 192.168.10.03
State: 4, count: 1

IP: 192.168.10.07
State: 1, count: 1

IP: 192.168.10.11
State: 2, count: 1
State: 4, count: 1

IP: 192.168.10.26
State: 2, count: 1
State: 4, count: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` the lines that you want to handle, that is possible with `sed`.
Get 2 substrings from your line with `sed`, sort and count:

```
sed -n '/state:: [24] .*@/ s/.*:: \([24]\)[^@]*@\([^:]*\).*/State \1 IP \2/p' file |
 sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```